# Best practice for GA goals and cleaner completion URLs?

Tags: google, google-analytics, goal-tracking

Not sure how to look this up but some of what I've come across doesn't seem to answer what I'm looking for.

So two things:

Is there a method to clear or track the URLs with ad parameters? (I still want to track the URLs). So my goals are set up and if someone converted at the home page it'll show `'/'` which is correct but if they came from an ad the Goal Completion Location shows `'/?-_property_name=&test...'` something along those lines. Is there a way to attribute that ad url to the home page in GA?

Also, is there a best method to track a single form on two separate pages (/floor-plans/ and /new-homes/)? Like would it be wise to funnel the submissions to a single goal and spend some time looking at the data to look at where the conversions come from or create their own goals in GA?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying for with the ad parameters? Do you want them gone generally, but the pageviews/goal completions still tracked? Or are you hoping to have them show in some places but not in others?

Comment: Yes so when I look at the conversions in the Goal Completion Location on the homepage I see all those who converted there but there's URLs that also converted in the homepage but come from ads so the URLs will look something like '/?keyword=text&ppc=campaign/'. But it's counting as a new page when it should be counted as the homepage. Is there a best practice for that? here's the best I can share https://imgur.com/a/zROa417

Comment: The items boxed in red should be attributed to the home page '/' which I also highlighted in the imgur link